# Pass php variable though open.window

Tags: php, javascript

I'm pretty new to javascript so please excuse this question if it seems pretty nooby.  I am writing an online calendar to book engineer's jobs so we need to be able to look at the calendar whilst looking at and editing individual jobs.  After much deliberation I decided the best way to do this is by opening the jobs in a new window using window.open.  However, I would like to pass the job id via the url in order to pass it to the new window but for love nor money I can't work it out or find a solution.  Here is my code so far

```
function open_win() 
{
    window.open('job_detail.php', '_blank','toolbar=0,location=no,menubar=0,height=400,width=400,left=200, top=300');

}

<a href="#" onclick="open_win()" ><? echo $row['name']; ?></a>
```

The $row['name'] is the value of the link and the value I want to pass will be held in $row['id'] or $job_id.  I just can't work out where to put it so it passes on.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a parameter?

```
function open_win(id) {
    window.open('job_detail.php?id=' + id, '_blank','toolbar=0,location=no,menubar=0,height=400,width=400,left=200, top=300');
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="open_win(<?= $row['id'] ?>)"><? echo $row['name']; ?></a>
```

Comment: @user1267224 this is the way to do it and then OP can just retrieve the value using `$_GET['id']` or `$_REQUEST['id']` on the "job_detail.php" page.

Comment: Thanks for that, I tried it then then the link wouldn't do anything. I ended up using <a href="#" onclick="window.open('job_detail.php?id=<? echo $row['id']; ?>', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=no,menubar=0,height=400,width=400,left=200, top=300')" ><? echo $row['name']; ?></a> which did the trick

Comment: @user1267224: Oh, I assumed `id` was an integer. If it was a string, you'd have needed to put quotes around it. But you got it fixed, so nevermind :)